# how to move a mysql database to another mount point

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I have a MySQL database, it is getting larger and larger and I want to move the whole database to another mount point, where I have enough storage. I want my current data to be transferred, and that new data get saved to the new position.

software stack: MySQL 5 running on FreeBSD 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course other answers are valid. But if you want to keep the default configuration, do following:

1. stop mysqld
2. `mv  /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql.backup`
3. mount your new partition under `/var/lib/mysql`
4. `cp -r /var/lib/mysql.backup /var/lib/mysql`
5. start mysqld

Comment: only `cp -pr /var/lib/mysql.backup/* /var/lib/mysql` worked for me as intended.

Comment: nothing works still endup with the same issue as: http://serverfault.com/questions/503887/cant-start-mysql-after-changing-directories

Answer (score 3):

- Stop mysqld
- Copy /var/lib/mysql (or whatever $datadir in my.cnf was set to) to the new location
- Either mount the new location under the old $datadir or modify the MySQL configuration in the file my.cnf to reflect the new location.
- Start mysqld

There's no magic involved. ;)
But you should make sure, that you copy all permissions with the files of MySQL.

Comment: magic is needed as nothing works, I'm having the same issue as http://serverfault.com/questions/503887/cant-start-mysql-after-changing-directories

Answer (score 2):

If you can tolerate the database being down for the move:

1. Shutdown MySQL
2. rsync the files to the new mount point
3. either:

   1. change `mysql.conf` to tell MySQL where to find the files, or
   2. make the current directory a symlnk to the new one
4. restart MySQL

Comment: doesn't work: http://serverfault.com/questions/503887/cant-start-mysql-after-changing-directories

Comment: Yes, it works, I've done it numerous times.  What you've done by mounting a whole new file system on top of the original location is fine, too.