# How to move MYSQL 5.0 Database from one server to another

Tags: mysql

My need is to move the MYSQL 5.0 database from my development m/c to actual production m/c,
How I can do this ???
On production m/c MYSQL is not installed, MY SQL 3.5 drivers are present.
but on my m/c MYSQL 5.0 and MYSQLDrivers 5.0 are resent so will on production server 3.5 driver will support 5.0 vertion...If I created DSN with 3.5 will it support database of 5.0?

Thanks

Comment: See also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743245/how-to-move-a-mysql-database-to-another-mount-point , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113768/how-to-move-local-mysql-db-up-to-remote-db-server , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859746/moving-mysql-files-across-servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step would be to install MySQL on the production server. If it's not, then there's no point in doing the migration, is there?

v3.5 drivers should be able to talk to a 5.x database, though you'll probably have some trouble. 3.x is positively stone age these days. Unless you have no control over the production server, there shouldn't be any reason to NOT upgrade to a 5.0/5.1 server and driver set.